# Receive string in socket programming android

Tags: android

I am working on client server android application here my client is my application . I am sending string to server through wireless router . Sending of string is working fine  but I am not getting how to deal with response string from server.
here is my code for sending and receiving strings

for sending

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
InputStream is=socket.getInputStream();
int ch;
StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while((ch=(is.read))!=-1)
{
  byte b=(byte)ch;
  sb.append(b);
}
String response=sb.toString();
```